# How do you add/remove hidden in <p hidden> with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, hidden

How do you add and remove `'hidden'` from `<p hidden>My Text</p>`?

I tried removing the attribute and setting it to false but neither of them worked.

```js
  let p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  let myText;
    
  for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    if (p[i].innerHTML == "My Text") {
      myText = p[i];
      break;
    }
  }

  myText.removeAttribute("hidden"); // no effect
  myText.setAttribute("hidden", false); // no effect
```

Comment: `hidden` is a css property of a dom object.https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

Comment: What is your current `p` element looks like?

Comment: `p` element looks like this: `<p hidden>My Text<\p>`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks fine here. Try with this code if you wish.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
      <p hidden>My Text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

script

```
let p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
let myText;

for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  if (p[i].innerHTML == "My Text") {
    // console.log(myText, p[0].innerHTML);
    myText = p[i];
    break;
  }
}

myText.removeAttribute("hidden");
```

You can see in codePen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qozVaq

Answer (score 19):

Could you set an ID on the `<p>` tag and interact with it that way?

```
<p id="whatever" hidden>My Text</p>
```

And:

```
let p = document.getElementById('whatever');
p.removeAttribute("hidden");
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `addAttribute` and `removeAttribute` use:

```js
myText.hidden = false
// or
myText.hidden = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing comparison text works fine for me:

```
let p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    let myText;
    for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        var txt = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[i].innerHTML;
        if (p[i].innerHTML == txt) {
            myText = p[i];
            break;
        }
    }

myText.removeAttribute("hidden");
```

Here is the working version: https://jsfiddle.net/j0467m8m/15/

Answer (score 1):

I've got something similar, using js to set or remove hidden from a div, it works for fullscreen or 1200px, but didn't work for 690px:

```
let sidebar = document.querySelector(".dropdown-btn");
let dropdownSidebar = document.querySelector(".three");

dropdownSidebar.addEventListener("click", function(){
   sidebar.hasAttribute("hidden") ? sidebar.removeAttribute("hidden") : sidebar.setAttribute("hidden", "");
});
```

Comment: Demonstrating both add and remove.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function show(){
x = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
if(x[0].style.visibility === "hidden"){
   x[0].style.visibility = "visible"   
 }else{
   x[0].style.visibility = "hidden"  
}}
```

```html
<p >this is hidden</p>
<button onClick='show()'>show</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must have probably given your image a display of block, this can cause the error you have now. Remove display styling, and you should be good to go.